# Josephus problem, Base 2 reprentration with binomial?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was reading Josephus problem from book concrete maths (Donald E knuth) and at page 11 he gives the theory below after solving the problem itself (I couldn't understand the below theory and it's following parts...):

> Now that we’ve done the hard stuff (solved the problem) we seek the
>   soft: Every solution to a problem can be generalized so that it
>   applies to a wider class of problems. Once we’ve learned a technique,
>   it’s instructive to look at it closely and see how far we can go with
>   it. Hence, for the rest of this section, we will examine the solution
>   (1.9) and explore some generalizations of the recurrence (1.8). These
>   explorations will uncover the structure that underlies all such
>   problems. Powers of 2 played an important role in our finding the
>   solution, so it’s natural to look at the radix 2 representations of n
>   and J(n). Suppose n's binary expansion is

```
n = (b, b,-l . . bl bo)z ; // what is this?
```

that is,

```
n = bm2^m + bm-1*2^m-1 + ... + b1*2 + b0, //bm == b sub m
```

where each bi is either 0 or 1 and where the leading bit b, is 1. Recalling that `n = 2”+l` , we have, successively,

```
n = (l*bm-1*bm-2...b1*b0)2,
l = (0*bm-1*bm-2...b1*b0)2 ,
2l = (bm-1*bm-2...b1*b0*0)2,
2l+ 1 = (bm-1*bm-2...b1*b0*1 )2 ,
J(n) = (bm-1*bm-2...b1*b0*bm)2
```

**My question** is what are above equation and how did author deduced them?

(I understand binomial this form of binomial I never encountered, also I'm little idiot in maths , so please easy on me and good at explanation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean binary not binomial.

$n=(b_mb_{m-1}...b_1b_0)_2$ is just the binary representation of a number. Like you posted it represents $n=b_m2^m+b_{m-1}2^{m-1}+...+b_12+b_0$.

So for an example take n=123, in base 10 we can express this as $$123=1*10^2+2*10^1+3*10^0$$ which is the same as $(123)_{10}$. To express 123 in base 2, we have $$123=1*2^6+1*2^5+1*2^4+1*2^3+0*2^2+1*2^1+1*2^0$$ which is the same as $(1111011)_2$.

From the previous page in the book it was proven using induction that $J(2^m+l)=2l+1$ for $m\geq0$ and $0\leq l<2^m$. All the author wants to do now is to represent $2^m+l$ and $2l+1$ using binary.

Notice that 
$$2^m+l=1*2^m+b_{m-1}2^{m-1}+...+b_1*2^1+b_0*2^0=(1b_{m-1}b_{m-2}...b_1b_0)_2$$ and since we know $0\leq l<2^m$ it must be the case that $l=(0b_{m-1}b_{m-2}...b_1b_0)_2$ (remember these are the same $b_i$'s in the representation for $2^m+l$ above). It should be quite easy to see why $2l=(b_{m-1}b_{m-2}...b_1b_00)_2$, i.e. $$2(0*2^{m}+b_{m-1}*2^{m-1}+b_{m-2}*2^{m-2}+...+b_1*2^1+b_0*2^0)$$all powers of 2 simply increase by 1. The last two equations $2l+1$ and $J(n)$ I leave to you.